# Lock windows desktop from Java after timeout

Tags: java, windows, timeout, lockout

I want my java app to lock the windows desktop after a specific timeout.  I have a timer which works fine, but I can't seem to execute the command to lock the workstation.

```
javax.swing.Timer tim = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   System.out.println("CARD NOT PRESENT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
   // LOCK SCREEN
   Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
   Process pr = rt.exec("%windir%/System32/rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation");
   }
});
```

Is there some mistake in this?  Or maybe an easier way to do this?

Comment: do you see the `CARD NOT PRESENT!...` text printed on standard out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a better way to test this :

1) put the command in a .bat file.

2) Run the bat file.  does it work ?

3) If so , call the .bat file in your code.

4) Does it work ?  If so, then you are done.  I dont think there is any value in encoding windows specific code into runtime exec, just keep the bat file as a seperate file in your app .

Runtime.exec sometimes fails because the paths arent the same inside the JVM as they are in the native os.

Answer (score 5):

Try absolute location:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation");
```

Answer (score 4):

This is working as well (tested on Windows 7 x86):

```
final String path = System.getenv("windir") + File.separator + "System32" + File.separator + "rundll32.exe";
Process pr = rt.exec(path + " user32.dll,LockWorkStation");
```